# getting datetime from different location

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012

I need a time from different location. My server resides in the US but I need time from Australia.

when I save records in database, I use DateTime.Now() C# function. Is there a way I can get and save Australian time even though the server where my website is hosted is in US?

If there is any database solution then that will be ok too. I am using sql server

Comment: I recommend you not to use some local time. Save UTC time. And convert it to local US or Australia time for each client

Comment: http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/

Comment: Alternatively, use datetimeoffset to store the local time as the UTC time plus local offset from UTC.

Comment: The Problem with Time & Timezones - Computerphile - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Comment: Sergey is correct. If you are using SQL server 2008 > then I suggest to use DateTimeOffset as a datatype in the db and your models. Then you could possibly make your server support multiple timezones at the same time

Answer (score 5):

This is how you get your local time now:

```
DateTime yourLocalTime = DateTime.Now;
```

You can get current [**UTC**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) time with [DateTime.UtcNow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or by converting local time to UTC time:

```
DateTime utcTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime utcTime = yourLocalTime.ToUniversalTime();
```

Save this time to database instead of saving some local time. How to get your local time from UTC time:

```
DateTime yourLocalTime = utcTime.ToLocalTime();
```

How to get time in other time zone:

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Tokyo Standard Time");
DateTime tokyoLocalTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime, timeZone);
```

Comment: Statement:DateTime tokyoLocalTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime, timeZone); will return time. I also need date. How can I get the date part too?

Comment: @fawadali why do you think `ConvertTimeFromUtc` does not return date part?